# MVC Split up page into ListView and DetailsView

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I made the listview and the detailsview seperately in MVC

Is it possible to combine them on one page 
using:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
    <div id="list">
        @{Html.RenderAction("List");}
    </div>
    <div id="details">
        @{Html.RenderAction("Detail");}
    </div>
</div>
```

But, the list and the details page are coming from two different controllers.

You should have a small list and then click on details and stay on the same page to get a details page (actually also a list in my case, with records like list of experiences), in my example this is also a list from another controller 
 but with the id giving to the second controller.

It should be like this:

[sample views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01laO.jpg)

Comment: yes possible. but what you have tried from your side

Comment: I think it is better to do it using partial views. Every time you click on a Details button from the left list, the button calls an Ajax code that calls the `Detail` action which returns the Details partial view and then update that section of the page.

Comment: Yes - You just need to specify the controller name in the 2nd argument - @{Html.RenderAction("List", controllerName);}` But if you want to respond to client side events and update the page, then you need to use javascript and ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, maybe Ajax, you are right.
I now added a second model to the page using the following:

```
@using Project.Models
@using Project.ViewModels
@model MultipleModelInOneView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

    <table class="table table-active table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Title1
            </th>
            <th>
                Title2
            </th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (Detail details in Model.Details)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@details.Column1
                </td>
                <td>@details.Column2
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <table class="table table-active table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Title1
            </th>
            <th>
                Title2
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (Moredetail moredetail in Model.MoreDetails)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@moredetail.Column1 
                </td>
                <td>@moredetail.Column2
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

in Folder ViewModels:

```
public class MultipleModelInOneView
{
    public IEnumerable<Detail> Details { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Moredetail> MoreDetails { get; set; }
}
```